# eth_sendRawTransaction parameter formatting

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, sendrawtransaction

we have a JSON RPC method eth_sendRawTransaction as specified [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendrawtransaction).

how is the raw transaction data formatted? I can't seem to find this anywhere.

I'm guessing it consists of a signed transaction struct serialized and encoded in some way, but it doesn't explicitly say.

Comment: it's RLP encoded, https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP

Comment: `core/types/transaction.go`, `core/types/transaction_signing.go`, `core/types/transaction_test.go` might help